# Can a process be DoSed by interfering with its compare-exchange loops?

Tags: denial-of-service

Consider a file accessed by multiple processes; the processes map the file to memory and then use lock-free operations to synchronize (for example, use atomic-add to allocate an offset in the file to write to).

The atomic operations might be lock-free, but not wait-free. On x86 for example, atomic-max would be implemented as a compare-exchange loop (fetch previous value, compute the new maximum, compare-exchange, repeat if the previous value changed). Now, a malicious process could hammer the memory location with writes to make the compare-exchange constantly fail, thus blocking the other processes forever.

Is this a real issue that I need to protect against? Or does the unpredictable timing of modern processors make such attacks impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Most interesting question.

In theory, such an attack would be possible if we were to make CAS (compare-and-swap) intentionally always fail.

For that to happen (from a **hardware perspective**), the underlying hardware should allow all competing threads to fail, which it normally should not, because a CAS that could fail for all threads could lead to live-lock situations (and non-deterministic behavior).

Furthermore, techniques such as exponential back-off (like in the case of the Ethernet protocol) should be used before retrying CAS.

From a **software perspective**, if not sure of the hardware behind, one can make sure to use things such AtomicX.compareAndSet (JAVA SE 7,8) instead of AtomicX.weakCompareAndSet, which practically makes sure simultaneous fails of all threads is excluded.

As example, win32 implementation is safe:

```
   void LockFreeQueue::push(Node* newHead)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        // Copy shared var  to local.
        Node* oldHead = m_Head;

        // Do some work, not yet visible to other threads.
        newHead->next = oldHead;

        // Attempt to publish changes to the shared variable.
        // If the shared var hasn't changed, the CAS succeeds and we return.
        // Otherwise, repeat.
        if (_InterlockedCompareExchange(&m_Head, newHead, oldHead) == oldHead)
            return;
    }
}
```

The above is loop free because if the test fails for one thread, it means it must have succeeded for another.